# PHP: String from JPEG EXIF being treated as integer

Tags: php, integer, exif

Be kind, I'm fairly new to this and am probably missing something obvious.

I'm setting up an e-commerce site. Products are all unique, photographed individually, and sold offline also. Order volume is low, and I want to be able to manage online stock by simply adding or deleting image files in a directory. To this end, I'm storing product code and product size (which determines price) in the EXIF data of the JPEG files. Intent is to have a CSV generated and imported to the shop software every hour or so.

BUT, I can't work out why can't perform a calculation on a string extracted from the EXIF data.

Here's my bad code:

```
    $dir    = '.';
    $all_names = scandir($dir);
    $ignore = array(".", "..", "sold", "onhold", "exifread.php");
    $files = array_diff($all_names, $ignore);


    foreach ($files as $file) {

    $exif = exif_read_data($file, 0, true);

    $ifd0 = $exif[IFD0];

    $size = $ifd0['Comments'];
    $prod_code = $ifd0['Author'];
    $time_taken = $ifd0['DateTime'];
    $price_per_m2 = 102;
    $gst = 1.1;
    $total_price = ($size * $price_per_m2) * $gst;

    echo "$file;$size;$prod_code;$time_taken;$total_price<br />\n";
    }

    ?>
```

$size is being treated as an integer, but sizes are all in m2, with two decimal places (e.g. 3.45).

I tried a str_replace to remove the '.' and multiplying by 1.02 instead of 102, but while $size is echoed correctly (e.g. 345), the multiplication ($total_price) shows that $size is still treated as an ineger (e.g. 3).

Comment: Show the bytes that make up the data.

Comment: I'm not 100% certain what you mean, but I get 51 0 46 0 50 0 48 0 0 0 from for($i = 0; $i < strlen($size); $i++)
{
   echo ord($size[$i])." ";
}... when the value of $size is should be 3.20

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The EXIF data is encoded as UTF-16LE. You will need to convert it to ASCII via iconv or the like before you can use it in calculations so that it doesn't get truncated at the first NUL.

Comment: THANKYOU!         $size = iconv('UTF-16LE', 'ASCII//TRANSLIT', $ifd0['Comments']); works perfectly!